# How to make a pre-emptive basic authentication call using savon client in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am doing the following code in savon but unable to do as it requires pre-emptive authorization. I have verified in soapUI but unable to run in savon.
Could somebody help?

```
client = Savon.client(ssl_verify_mode: :none) do
  wsdl '/Users/sp/jda_notifications/TransportationManagerService.wsdl'
  endpoint 'http://localhost:8088/webservices/services/TransportationManager'
  basic_auth('VENTURE', 'VENTURE')
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the exact same problem

here the solution :

```
realm = Base64.strict_encode64("VENTURE:VENTURE")
client = Savon.client(
    wsdl:'/Users/sp/jda_notifications/TransportationManagerService.wsdl',
    headers: { 'Authorization' => "Basic #{realm}"}
)
```

We have to use headers which edit http headers and not soap_header.